# Spring Boot Application connection to PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I very recently started learning Java and spring boot and I was following a youtube tutorial on how to build a small project, but when it got to the point of checking the connection to the database i got this message:

```
customer=# \dt
Did not find any relations.
```

And because i'm very much unfamilar with java and spring boot, i find myself debugging with no clear workflow. If anyone could guide me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it.

Here is my code:

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public GreetingResponse greeting(){
        GreetingResponse greetingString = new GreetingResponse(
                "Hello",
                List.of("Python", "Python", "Python"),
                new Person("Batool", 28, 500_000)
        );
        return greetingString;


    }

    record Person(String name, int age, double savings){

    }
    record GreetingResponse(
            String greeting,
            List<String> favProgrammingLanguages,
            Person person
    ){
    }
```

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.Objects;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "customer_id_sequence", sequenceName = "customer_id_sequence")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "customer_id_sequence")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;


    public Customer(Integer id, String name, String email, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer customer = (Customer) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, customer.id) && Objects.equals(name, customer.name) && Objects.equals(email, customer.email) && Objects.equals(age, customer.age);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, email, age);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: <>
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <>
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5332/customer
    username: <>
    password: <>
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format-sql: true
      show-sql: true
    main:
      web-development-type: servlet
```

Answer (score 0):

You are telling Spring to connect to a database server with a hostname of `db`. But that `db` hostname will only work from within the docker bridge network created inside docker-compose. If you were running the Spring Boot application as another service inside the docker-compose file, then that address would work. But you don't appear to be doing that.

You most likely need to change the datasource URL in the Spring config file to this:

```
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5332/customer
```

Because this line in your docker-compose file is exposing the database service on port `5332` on your local computer, or `localhost`:

```
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
```

Comment: I actually changed to "db" instead of localhost after seeing a couple of answer on stackoverflow, but now I changed it back to localhost and this didn't take care of the issue. I faced other problems and tbh I'm not sure how to exactly approach them.

the localhost is working fine, the site is working, it's just the connection that's not working, also, when i run Customer.java from the terminal i get different errors and I can't tell if this is what's causing the issue

Comment: the weird thing is now i get this message when i run Main.java:

`Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@43471a7e`

But when i open the shell to check the connection to the database customer, is till get:'Did not find any relations.'

Comment: If you are getting "Did not find any relations" then I think you have successfully connected your Java application to the database server. Now you are getting issues because you either haven't created the appropriate database tables yet, or the tables you have created don't have any data in them yet.

Comment: i could insert into the table manually, but if i create api's endpoints where they have to retrieve data from the tables this is where the issue arises as i would get an empty list back. Hope it's clearer now because it's really difficult for me to pin point the problem's source

Comment: It sounds like your code is getting an error retrieving data, because no data exists yet. It really sounds more like it is functioning as intended than an actual error. In any case I think you have resolved your database connection issue which was the issue you posted about in your original question. I suggest asking a new question about the "did not find relations" issue.

Comment: yes, you're right but if you have any idea as to why this is happening I'd very much appreciate your input before I upload a new question

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc connection has to find the schema name, and because an error that eventually bubbles up thru spring, to the application.
This connects:

1. spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=public
2. spring.datasource.username = postgres
3. spring.datasource.password = password
4. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

worked for me